# how to convert my TIMESTAMP to UTC timestamp in magento

Tags: php, magento, datetime, timezone, timestamp

i found many articals on this but none of give proper soluation

my current system timezone is = `'asia/Kolkata'`

my current magento timezone is `'asia/shanghai'`

this give me de correct `UTC` time here system time is `'2013-06-26 15:34:00'`

```
   $timezone = date_default_timezone_get();
   date_default_timezone_set($timezone);

   $now = Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(time());
   $current_date= date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

so here $current_date = `'2013-06-26 18:04:30'`

but i have another mytimestamp..... ex :- $time = `'2013-06-26 15:34:00'`;

```
   $scheduletime = '2013-06-26 15:19:00';
   $dateTimestamp = Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(strtotime($scheduletime));
   $schedule_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($scheduletime));
```

so here $schedule_time = `'2013-06-26 23:34:00'`

so actually what i want is to get difference between this two time and it should be : 0

Comment: Timestamps are UTC it's the timezone you need to correct to get a proper time.

Comment: thankx for your reply....can you give me example?

Comment: If you want to use `asia/Kolkata` as your timezone in your application you can either set that in php.ini or use `date_default_timezone_set('asia/Kolkata')` on top of your scripts. Timestamps are UTC by standard, the timezone you provide will add/substract from a timestamp to give you the date/time of that timestamp in that given timezone

Comment: is it possible to convert `'2013-06-26 15:19:00'` this time into UTC? with respect to 'asia/Kolkata'

Comment: `strtotime('2013-06-26 15:19:00')` will give you the timestamp that responds to that datetime in UTC timezone

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->gmtDate();
```

Note: UTC and GMT are equal.

Answer (score 2):

Use strtotime to generate a timestamp from the given string (interpreted as local time) and use gmdate to get it as a formatted UTC date back.

**For example**

As requested, here’s a simple example:

```
echo gmdate('d.m.Y H:i', strtotime('2012-06-28 23:55'));
```

or you can also use local setting with store like below

```
Mage::app()->getLocale()->storeDate(
            $this->getStore(),
            Varien_Date::toTimestamp($this->getCreatedAt()),
            true
        );
```

where `$this->getCreatedAt()` your Database date.

Comment: pls check my updated answer will sure help you to convert with your magento store